# Possible sharding existing ArangoDB database?

Tags: database, cluster-computing, arangodb

I have one simple question. If I develop now my game on single ArangoDB database, and if it grows big, would it be possible to extend my existing database/collection with coordinators and shards included with redundancy?

Thanks, Vili

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will be able to use [arangodump](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpBulkImports/Arangodump.html) to get a dump of your non sharded database.

You actually get two files per collection:

- the payload, one json document per line (*.data.json)
- the collection description (*.structure.json)

You then could [modify the collection description to configure more than one shard plus its parameters](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpBulkImports/Arangorestore.html#using-arangorestore-with-sharding), and [restore](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpBulkImports/Arangorestore.html) it into a cluster setup.

You may however need to re-tune your queries for optimal performance in the clustered situation. You should definitely calculate that you first need to test-drive your application with the new setup.

Comment: Ok cool, this work falls under "Maintenance time". Queries can be optimized latter when database became sharded/clustered right? Can I expect worse performance or just about the same with same queries?

Comment: Of course I will test-drive my app before going into the wild :).

Comment: Ok one more question if I can..

What about sharding database from a start then when time comes, resizing it? Would that be easier/more sensible?

Comment: since clustering involves more network communication, you allways will have a higher latency if you compare two similar queries on an idle environment. However, if you (most probably) write to several disks, throughput may improve - and if you would have less possibility for disk i/o being the bottleneck.   I'd start simple first, get into production, and prepare workpackages for sharding later on.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then sharding won't be necessary since I will run database on SSD (cloud).